# Symfony: using different validation constraints for same field in inheritance?

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, inheritance, constraints

I have a "Parent' class with a file property and this class has many children. Each of this child use the common property in a different way. For example, one class uses it to upload a PDF. Another one can use it to upload a JPEG. Therefore, I would like to have different validation rules for each child. Is there a way to do it?

I tried doing it in a validation.yml file but it says the child does not have the property as it's a parent property. Ex:

```
MyBundle\Entity\Child1:
    properties:
        file:
            - File:
                maxSize: 1024k
                mimeTypes: [application/pdf, application/x-pdf]
                mimeTypesMessage: Please upload a valid PDF

MyBundle\Entity\Child2:
    properties:
        file:
            - File:
                maxSize: 1024k
                mimeTypes: [image/png]
                mimeTypesMessage: Please upload a valid PNG
```

Comment: Therefor you have to declare you file property als protected in parent and childs entity classes. That works with mapped superclass inheritance, not sure for your use case.

Comment: But you can also define the two constraints by the parent and use Validation Groups : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups

Comment: @Alsatian It's a Single Table Inheritance so it must be the same. However, I didn't understand your comment. Should I declare twice the property? In the parent and in the child? About validation groups, I tried that but I'm not sure I can declare twice the same rule. Do you have any example? Thanks.

Comment: @Alsatian I just asked another question because I think my problem is larger than what I explained here. However, I keep this one because I think its a useful question anyway.

The new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37455206/symfony-only-one-file-entity-and-different-validation-rules-for-each-associatio

Comment: Yes try it with the property declared as protected in the parent class and the child classes. It works so for mapped Superclass may be also here ...

Yes you can declare twice the same rule and set "groups" on each of them.