# Symfony: Only one file entity and different validation rules for each association?

Tags: validation, symfony, doctrine-orm, constraints, symfony-forms

In my current project, I decided to create only one translatable File entity and reuse it for all image/document properties I have. For the translations, I uses Knp Doctrine Behaviors Translatable. So here is the code.

The file class:

```
class File
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

The translatable file class:

```
class FileTranslation
{
    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translation;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    public $path;

    /**
     * @Assert\File()
     */
    private $file;

    /*
     * Non tracked parameter
     */
    public $folder;

    /**
     * Set name.
     *
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * Get name.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set path.
     *
     * @param string $path
     */
    public function setPath($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * Get path.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPath()
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * Set folder
     *
     * @param string $folder
     *
     * @return File
     */
    public function setFolder($folder)
    {
        $this->folder = $folder;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get folder
     *
     * @return File
     */
    public function getFolder()
    {
        return $this->folder;
    }
}
```

And then an example of how it's used in another entity (User) to create an image property:

```
class User 
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="File", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $image;
}
```

Nothing new. I just followed Symfony/Knp documentation and it works fine. However, now I want to add different validation rules each time I create a new property like $image for different entities. What is the best strategy here?

Each time I try to add a validation rule related to file in the $image property, for instance, it says it cannot find a file.

Answer (score 1):

you can have specific validator for each entity:

```
     /**
     * vérification des constraintes
     * @Assert\Callback
     */
    public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        var_dump($this->image);// do your check here
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you give me more details about your solution? Sorry, but I didn't undesrtand it. Should I create my own validator? 

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

And how do I define the constraints in the entities?

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the same problem, I finally did what @sylvain said and I created my custom validators:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html

This is a great tutorial, btw:

https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/question-answer-day/custom-validation-property-path

It works fine. However, I still think the @valid constraint should have worked and I don't understand why it didn't.